# How to create docker-machine in aws? Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to do a docker-machine with AWS in EC2, but when I write this:

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 aws-prod
```

I get the following error and I dont find how to solve it:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(aws-prod) Launching instance...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded
```

Anyone knows how it is possible to solve it??

Thanks in advance